# How to change ear speaker to loud in Angular

Tags: angular, toggle, speaker, agora

I am working on an Angular project in which users can make and receive calls. I am using Agora for audio-video calls, and it's working fine. I have added functions to toggle the microphone and camera, and they are working as expected. Now, for mobile users or those who open my link in a mobile browser, I want to add a toggle speaker function to switch between the ear speaker and loudspeaker. However, I am unable to find a useful answer.

I want to add toggle speaker function in which I can can to ear speaker to loud speaker in Angular.

I tried to search for it on Google but all the answers are for different scenario.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: Could you point to the Agora docs? I wonder if the frontend JS API has a way to choose between audio devices?

Comment: Agora don't provide any thing related to change speaker